# Can't login into account - Magento 2.3.4 update

Tags: login, customer-login

I've update to Magento 2.3.4 and after the update, for most of the users that try to login, we get the next report

`{"0":"Unable to send the cookie. Size of 'mage-messages' is 4155 bytes.","1":"#1 Magento\\Framework\\Stdlib\\Cookie\\PhpCookieManager->setCookie('mage-messages', '[{\"type\":\"error\"...', array('duration' => 31536000, 'path' => '\/', 'http_only' => false)) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Stdlib\/Cookie\/PhpCookieManager.php:121]\n#2 Magento\\Framework\\Stdlib\\Cookie\\PhpCookieManager->setPublicCookie('mage-messages', '[{\"type\":\"error\"...', &Magento\\Framework\\Stdlib\\Cookie\\PublicCookieMetadata#000000001a59503b000000007930b032#) called at [vendor\/magento\/module-theme\/Controller\/Result\/MessagePlugin.php:140]\n#3 Magento\\Theme\\Controller\\Result\\MessagePlugin->setCookie(array(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'), array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Invalid Form Key...'))) called at [vendor\/magento\/module-theme\/Controller\/Result\/MessagePlugin.php:95]\n#4 Magento\\Theme\\Controller\\Result\\MessagePlugin->afterRenderResult(&Magento\\Framework\\Controller\\Result\\Redirect\\Interceptor#000000001a5957b2000000007930b032#, &Magento\\Framework\\Controller\\Result\\Redirect\\Interceptor#000000001a5957b2000000007930b032#, &Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor#000000001a595485000000007930b032#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:146]\n#5 Magento\\Framework\\Controller\\Result\\Redirect\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor#000000001a595485000000007930b032#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#6 Magento\\Framework\\Controller\\Result\\Redirect\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor#000000001a595485000000007930b032#), NULL) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/Controller\/Result\/Redirect\/Interceptor.php:26]\n#7 Magento\\Framework\\Controller\\Result\\Redirect\\Interceptor->renderResult(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor#000000001a595485000000007930b032#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php:120]\n#8 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php:24]\n#9 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:261]\n#10 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor#000000001a59549b000000007930b032#) called at [index.php:39]\n","url":"\/downloader\/gutuie.ro\/downloader\/","script_name":"\/index.php","report_id":"764afd02bda351efe574b979fe4dce10c624e9cb56b4556df01d7838441ded9c"}`

If I login in incognito page is working. If I login into other browser that Google Chrome is working. If I clean browser data in Google Chrome then is working also.

The problem is that a lot of customers cannot login and they are not going to another browser.

Can someone please help with this?

**UPDATE**

This error is fixed an it was because of Amasty GDPR cookie plugin. Now is showing on the screen "Invalid form key..." and when I look in cookies I see 2 records of "form_key".

How can I update or create a module that is deleting both of them and adding only one?

Answer (score 0):

It was a module throwing a large error message on login.

An error message is larger than the `MAX_COOKIE_SIZE`.

It's path is `vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php`

Try to edit a larger value for it and redeploy your site.

Reference: [Unable to send the cookie](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8276)

Comment: Can you please be more specific? From what I know, if is trowing the error 'Invalid Form Key", then it has to be display on the screen. I really do not understand what I have to change.

Comment: I've made an update to the post, maybe you can look at it